# How to change display of people search results in SharePoint 2010?

Tags: search-results

I am using SharePoint 2010. I have created a people directory page using the People search results page layout. When I search for a user, the results only display name. I would like it to display Title, Department, Phone number, Ask me about etc. How can I add these columns?

Comment: This would be avery long answer (and sadly I lack the time to write that right now). But here is a great tutorial on what you need to do: https://www.premierpointsolutions.com/training/help-and-how-to-articles/how-to-show-the-fax-number-in-people-search-results-in-sharepoint-2010/

Comment: I actually do not have access to central admin but the columns I need to display already exist. I have made the changes in the web part but I am still not seeing all the fields that I want to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard search result web part does not show any results unless a query is specified. To get all people to show up by default we need to specify either a fixed keyword query or append text to the query in the People Search Core Results web part properties. If we specify a fixed keyword query the web part will always display results for the specified search query on the page regardless of whether the user has entered a search query. If we select append text to query then when the user types a query we will see results from a search query that includes both the text the user entered and the text in the web part properties. For our people directory we can use this to show a default set of results (i.e. all people) but let the user refine this further by entering text (e.g. a person’s name or a department). The query we need to enter to retrieve all people is contentclass:spspeople.

You now have a list of people that will be displayed as soon as the user navigates to our custom people results page. By default we also have some refinements that appear if matching metadata is found within the result set. These are View matches by Name or Profile, Job Title, Organization and Managed Metadata columns (these pull out information such as Past projects, Ask Me About and other Managed Metadata fields contained in the edit profile screen). We can change these to show other metadata properties that are defined in our search centre. Some other properties that might be relevant are Department, Job Title and/or Past Projects.

This is the [solution](http://www.sharepointconfig.com/2011/05/how-to-create-a-simple-sharepoint-2010-people-directory/) to your question

Comment: I followed this tutorial and on step 4 when I am meant to see all the info about the users, I see all of the users but I see only Name, Title and Department. I want name, title, department, phone number, email and picture, if possible.